# How do I share data in Next.js 14

Tags: react-server-components, next.js14

How do I share data in a next.js 14 hierarchy?
I have the following project file structure and would like to check whether or not a team exists in the layout.tsx and then fetch some data from a database that I need to perform another request when navigating to the individual routes. How do I do this?

The children seem to load before the layout does causing an error.
How do I get the data shared across the sub routes?

[image]